# python pygtk-demo how to add a scrolledwindow to the treeview widget?

Tags: pygtk

I just want to develop a gtk program in python which contains two basic widgets (treeview and Notebook) like pygtk-demo program.Left side is the treeview and right side could display the each item's content of treeview.

Now I want to add a scrolledwindow to the treeview to make it scrollable, I tried several ways but unfortunately all of them didn't work.

So I raise a question here, could anyone help working on it ? Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Hpaned widget instead of the hbox to make the treeview scrollable.